# Can I create custom framebuffer and render to it in cocos2dx?

Tags: opengl, c++, cocos2d-x, frame-buffer

I want to do post processing effects so I was thinking If I could just make custom framebuffer in cocos2dx like OpenGL and render the ALL SCENES objects in it. I want a single frame buffer for all scenes. Is there any 
 way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some theory and practise on framebuffers:https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers it also explaines how to implement some very simple post-processing effects

Answer (score 0):

Framebuffers will be your friend. You can create as many as you wish with `glCreateFramebuffers()`. [Here is a documentation page](http://docs.gl/gl4/glDrawBuffers), which lists all the handy functions for doing that in "raw" OpenGL.

[cocos2d has the `RenderTexture` class, which will fit also your needs](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/3.0/manual/en/asset/render-texture.html?).